# What parameter settings make this expression $\Omega(1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I feel a bit silly for asking this, but here goes...

I have the expression:

$$(1 - (1 - n^{c+d-1})^{n^{2d}})^{n^{2-2d}}$$

We can assume $d$ is a constant somewhere in the range $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$.  Given $d$, I want to set $c$ to its minimum possible value such that the above expression does not vanish as $n$ goes to infinity (that is, it should not be $o(1)$ with respect to $n$).  The parameter $c$ should be a function of $d$, but not a function of $n$.

Wolfram times out on this computation.  What algebraic tricks can I use to simplify things and come up with an answer?

Comment: What is $M$?  Is it a positive integer?

Comment: What is $M$? $\textbf{}$

Comment: Whoops, there is no $M$, my bad vision mistook $2d$ in the highest exponents for $M$. :)  In that case, I suppose you require $c+d-1 \leq 0$?  Otherwise you'll run into issues taking fractional exponents of negative numbers.